# STM32WB15CC Nucleo Board not discoverable

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, stm32cubeide

I am new to STM32WB15CC. I am using the STM32WB15CC NUCLEO board. When I run the BLE example p2pserver on my board the board is discoverable and I can operate the LED via the STM BLE application. But when i created my own code enabled STM32WPAN BLE it isn't discovered

But when I created a new project enabled STM32 WPAN and everything various files were generated in that app_ble.c file contains the following code for discovery:
`BleApplicationContext.BleApplicationContext_legacy.advtServUUID[0] = NULL;`
`BleApplicationContext.BleApplicationContext_legacy.advtServUUIDlen = 0;`